How to set affinity in task manager
Can anyone help me understand the cause of this error window? Every time I attempt to "set affinity" on MsMpEng.exe in Task Manager a message appears stating my access is denied. Im not sure what is causing this and looking for answers online lead me to another user with the same problem in 2021 who didn't seem to find a solution. I think the same user made posts on the Windows and Autodesk forums and none of the replies on either forum have helped me.
From what I understand, a setting called User account control plays a role, but regardless of the slider position it doesn't seem to change the error message. I would really appreciate help with setting the affinity or gaining access.

MsMpEng.exe is Microsoft Defender. Microsoft Defender is programmed in such way that you have less access to do things to Microsoft Defender. Try to end the task, and the same thing happens, while it is not an issue for other processes.
This is to counter any tampering by viruses to shut down Microsoft Defender. Other virus scanners do a similar thing.
Setting the affinity would allow the virus scanner to not work correctly, which is why you can't do that either.
Do note, if you want to change the affinity of the virus scanner in order to combat an issue, doing so is not going to be the solution anyway. If you feel like the virus scanner is slowing down the system too much, look for other issues instead.
For example, having 2 virusscanners installed can seriously slow down a system as they then start fighting each other. Also, if you don't use the system too often, many processes will start at system start up as they haven't run in a while.

Thanks for the information, I probably should have mentioned that the root issue is Microsoft Defender using up my memory and occasionally the CPU. I've been going down a list of possible solutions to that root issue and changing the affinity was one of those solutions, thanks for the heads-up about two scanners, I was considering using another antivirus to scan MsMpEng.

It is okay to use another scanner, just make sure you check if Microsoft Defender is actually turned off. One common issue is that McAffee is installed by a third program and runs at the same time.
